# HTML position text in the center

Tags: html, text

I have this regular text code, which just basically displays a code. But I want to do so ARTIST stays in the middle, how do I do that?

```html
<div class="content">

  <b><p style="font-size:18px;line-
    height:10px;color:black;">SONGNAME</b> <br /></div>
<p style="font-size:18px; color:#FF2C55; line-height:0;">ARTIST<br/>
  </div>
```

I have tried position:fixed ; left:50% it did not worked. I know that there are a lot examples about that, but I can't find a similar code to mine.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add text-align:center in your ARTIST element.

```
<p style="font-size:18px; color:#FF2C55; line-height:0; text-align: center;">ARTIST</p>
```

You're also missing your closing tag on your SONGNAME element.
You can also do away with your br tags because divs are block elements inherently.

Answer (score 1):

Align the text for artist in the center. Your html also had some tag issues.

```css
#artist{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

<b><p style="font-size:18px;line-
height:10px;color:black;">SONGNAME</b> <br /></div>
<div id = 'artist'>
<p style="font-size:18px; color:#FF2C55; line-height:0;">ARTIST<br/>    
</p>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 'text-align:center;' to the style attribute of the element containing the text you want to center. example:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">

<b><p style="font-size:18px;line-
height:10px;color:black;">SONGNAME</b> <br /></div>
<p style="font-size:18px; color:#FF2C55; line-height:0; text-align:center;">ARTIST<br/>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```